# Removing top-level items from a jQuery set

Tags: jquery

I can't find a way to remove top-level items from a jQuery set. Here is my attempt:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var data = '<div id="node_1">aa</div> <div id="node_2">bb</div> <div id="node_3">cc</div>';
            var nodes = $(data);
            nodes.remove("#node_2");
            $("#container").append(nodes);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the following in the container:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="node_1">aa</div>
    <div id="node_3">cc</div>
</div>
```

But the node #2 is not removed.

How can I remove node #2 **before** inserting it into the document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you cannot remove DOM nodes that are not in the DOM at the moment.

You could use:

```
nodes = nodes.not('#b');
```

Keep in mind that even after (and during) manipulation, ids should be unique.

Comment: You can remove children elements though (e.g. if I wrap the 3 divs in a big one, then I can remove #2). Wrapping is the easy answer to my question, I was wondering if it could be avoided.

Comment: @Luper Rouch - AndreKR had it right, I edited my answer to reflect this method and how it might be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - Updated to support not inserting the div's into the DOM, and simply removing them pre-insertion.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var data = '<div class="1">aa</div> <div class="2">bb</div> <div class="3">cc</div>';
            $("#container_1").append(data);
            var nodes = jQuery(data).not('.2');   
            // In this example it's '.2',  
            // though you changed your id's in the original to something else
            $("#container_2").append(nodes);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container_1"> </div>
    <div id="container_2"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs uniqueness is not the problem here. I edited my example code with correct, unique IDs and only one container to avoid confusion.

Comment: Did you follow the rest of my suggestion? It stands true whether or not you're using a class or ID selector.

Comment: If you insist on keeping the `nodes` variable defined where it is, you can try using this: `var nodes = $(data).contents();` instead of `var nodes = $(data);`

Comment: I need to remove the node before insertion in the document.

Comment: Then you'll have to do it via string manipulation (I was probably wrong about my last comment RE .contents() ) because they're not technically in the DOM yet there isn't a function to remove them. I'd suggest regex, or just inserting it into the DOM then immediately removing it.

Comment: Currently I wrap my items in a div, and remove the nodes with .find() and .remove(). It works, but the wrapping adds complexity that I'd like to avoid.